# Scala - How to return simple raw type value from flat map?

Tags: scala, future

I have a simple code, where I want to get only one `boolean` value, but it is contained in a `Future` object:

```
def getValue(arg: String) : Boolean = for {
    data <- SomeObject.getData(arg) //SomeObject is in class constructor 
    value = data.getBooleanValue
} yield value
```

The problem here is I need to return `Future[Boolean]` instead of simple `boolean`. How I could change it to return only raw type?

Comment: you want `Future[Boolean]` or just `Boolean`?

Comment: To get the `Boolean` out from a `Future[Boolean]` you could just wait for the `Future` to finish, but that's a very bad thing to do. It make the whole `Future` thing pointless. Better to return `Future[Boolean]` instead.

Comment: @jacks jus Boolean

Comment: @jwvh - yes, but after return Future[Boolean] I need to use this value somwhere else.

Comment: Then use it as a `Future[Boolean]` instead of as a `Boolean` when you "use it somewhere else." It's a little more cumbersome but not that difficult. The whole point of a `Future` value is to leave it inside the `Future` for as long as possible. If you think you have to wait for a `Future` then think again. There are other solutions.

Comment: @jwvh about other solution you mean other Effect monads or other approach to my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you call an API that returns `Future` you need to chain your code to execute when that `Future` completes as far as you possibly can. Avoid waiting for `Future` to complete as long as possible.

So change the method to return `Future`:

```
def getValue(arg: String): Future[Boolean] =
  SomeObject.getData(arg).map(_.getBooleanValue)
```

Then rather than calling

```
nextMethod(getValue(myArg))
```

Use `map` on the `Future` like this:

```
getValue(myArg).map{ bool =>
  nextMethod(bool) // next processing step
}
```

This will give a new `Future` that will contain the result of the next step of the processing.

While this does require re-working the calling code, Scala makes this kind of code very easy to write. Keep chaining operations onto the previous `Future` until the processing is complete.

In most cases the code will end up with a side-effect operation such as sending a message or writing a file, and in this case there is no need to wait for the `Future` to complete.

On the rare occasions when you do need to wait for a `Future`, use `Await.result` to recover the final result of the chain of `Future`s

Comment: Thanks. But exactly I want to pass function like `getValue(arg: String)` as an argument to method and there it should be boolean, so I cannot map it here to get value?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to show to use the `Boolean` value as an argument to a method.